# Setup R shiny server in Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: r, azure, shiny

Is it possible to setup R shiny server (open source version) on Azure virtual machine?

Comment: Yes it is, http://www.r-bloggers.com/dockerizing-a-shiny-app/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install Shiny Server normally, connecting through ssh to your R Server following [this manual](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/):

```
sudo su - \
-c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
```

By default Rstudio Server `3838` port is not allowed, to alter this just

- go to your `Network Security groups`
- click security group associated with your virtual machine
- go to `Inbound security rules` within selected security group
- By default `default-allow-ssh` should be visible. Click `Add+` and allow new `name=allow-shiny` with `protocol=TCP` protocol and `port range=3838`
  And that's it.
- Open your browser and go to http://your_public_ip:3838 - You should see RStudio login panel.

Same process can be repeated to install RStudio Server

*If you have smaller instances some packages installation can be impossible due to memory insufficiency. You can resize your virtual machine just for a time of installation. After installation is done, resize back down*

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

It should be same as any other installation on a VM (On-Prem or on Azure). Currently windows platform is not supported so you can spin a VM on Azure with Ubuntu/Redhat/CentOS/SUSE and install R and Shiny Server. Instructions to download and install can be found in the link below

https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/